# copy files to remote servers checks

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have around of 100 remote servers and below how I am trying to copy some files 
from my PC to all of these remote servers but I want to do some checks

1- check if the connection to remote servers is available if NOT then go to next office

2-for user interaction

a- I am trying to color selected row at `datagridview1` to let user know at whcih office the progress is now and alos at `datagridview2` the same thing to let user know at which file the progress is now at specific  office but the interface freeze after starting sending file and no interaction happen what to do ?

b-how to color finished office row at green if success ?

**Update**

I used threading to solve form freezing so the feedback will back to user 
but problem not solved and still happen and nothing change please what should i do ???

```
public void PatchUpdates()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow OfficeListRow in DGV_OfficeList.Rows)
        {
            string OfficeIPAddress = OfficeListRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow FileListRow in DGV_FileList.Rows)
            {
                string SoruceFileNamePath = FileListRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                string DestinationFileNamePath = @"\\" + OfficeIPAddress + @"\usb1_1\test\" + Path.GetFileName(SoruceFileNamePath);


                Thread foregroundthread = new Thread(() => CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress));

                foregroundthread.Start();

                //check if connection to remote server is available
                if (CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress) == 1)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[3, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "Connected";
                    //file.copy(sorucefilenamepath, destinationfilenamepath, true); //copy files...
                }
                else if (CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress) == 0)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[3, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "disconnected";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

check connection method

```
public int CheckOffice(string _ipAddress)
{
    int timeout = 120;
    string data = "PingTestData";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    Ping PingSender = new Ping();
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

    options.DontFragment = true;

    PingReply reply = PingSender.Send(_ipAddress, timeout, buffer, options);

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That are a lot of questions and I think it is not a good idea to put them in one post. But nevertheless I could answer part of it:
1- I think your network check will not work. The method "GetIsNetworkAvailable" checks only, whether your computer is connected to network or not. You need to exceute a "ping" or something like that ([MSDN Ping class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)). Btw. If you use "return" after detection of a network failure you leave the method. Use "break" instead to leave the inner loop only.

2- As described in your link File.Copy is successful or throw an exception. So the way described there should be ok.

3- To show the progress you need to use a background worker thread([BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: i had update my post with the check using ping class 
now i got problem that the result returned in datagridview is not correct most of the time and sometimes the Whole pc freeze and restart ... is there anything you suggest about that check reomte server check part ?

Comment: @Sam : Result in data grid view is not correct -> Running in foreach loop does not change the current cell of the gridview which is updated by the ping response

Comment: @Sam PC freeze and restart -> Which OS are you using? This should not happen by normal application code on systems running windows NT 4 or later.

Comment: I am working on Windows 10... then when I  should update the datagridview or should I work on threading like suggested below knowing that I have no idea about thread so I hope there is a workaround I had tried to make interaction feedback to user out side the loop but that not possible since I am using data fRom the  loop and the nested loop

Comment: As Vikhram mentioned, you will need to use the hack with [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) or a background thread to show the progress. Otherwise each change (select row, change cell value) will be shown after the method is finished. To set the result to the right cell, make sure you write into the right one. See [Set selected row programmatically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/47e9c3ef-a8de-48c9-8e0d-4f3fdd34517e/datagridview-select-row-programatically?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Comment: Please I had update the code but problem not solve any suggestion or mistake I had made ?

Comment: You havent tried with Application.DoEvents yet, have you?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `PatchUpdates` is called from the GUI thread. If you update the `DataGridViewRow.Selected` in the loop where you are copying the files, then the GUI will never reflect that change, wince your function has not yet returned. There are a few ways to deal with it.

1. (Hackiest, but quickest) Call `Application.DoEvents()` after the `DataGridViewRow.Selected` change
2. (Cleaner solution but more efforts) Do this processing in a background thread and switch to GUI thread to update the GUI using the `Control.BeginInvoke()` method.

Now other than this, there are bunch of issues in your code:

The below line does not change, but is called in a loop to constantly check if your network connection is dropped or not. It might be what you actually need, but it kind of stood out as a mistake. Perhaps you want to use the `Ping` class to check if the machine is available?

```
if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
```

You have just toggled the value, probably for no reason. Maybe you were just trying to debug your solution. Or maybe you actually wanted the line to flash, but that won't happen with this code

```
OfficeListRow.Selected = true;
OfficeListRow.Selected = false;
```

Comment: first if you mean by PatchUpdates is cmd patch file i am already using patch file for that process now but i want to improve thing to make better so i  am working on c# project

Comment: second i know nothing about threading please would mind to give smal example ? what the other issues in my code please let me know ill work on them .. thanks

Comment: how you suggest to make the check of remote server availability? since I had update my post and used the ping class for now ...and yes that what I really want to check the connection is dropped or not so ill strat copy for the next server and not stacked at one server and the better thing is to copy to all server at same time

Comment: @Sam I don't know what you mean in your first comment. I just want to know whether your method `PatchUpdates` (that you have posted in the code) is called from the GUI/Event thread? This would happen if you call your method from, say, a button click event handler method.Have your tried the `Application.DoEvents` way before going the multi-threaded way, given that you don't have any background on multi-threaded?

Comment: Vikhram Please I had update the code but problem not solve any suggestion or mistake I had made ?