# Difference between ParameterizedThreadStart and encapsulating threaded method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was looking for the way of passing method with parameters to `ThreadStart()`
and I found I have to use [ParameterizedThreadStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) or encapsulating threaded method within a class now I need to know

1. What is the difference between these two ways ?
2. Is there any other ways ?

example

```
Thread foregroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myMethod(param1,param2,...)));
```

Comment: why not use Task.Run instead?

Comment: @Soner I have poor information about both way threading and run.task I am working on because of my original problem post here is it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189427/copy-files-to-remote-servers-checks
is it stable for my issues ? plus copying file to all servers at same times ?
someone here suggest me to use threading to solve  issues at original post

Comment: Using a lambda expression is the standard solution: new Thread(() => myMethod(param1, param2, etc));

Comment: Thank you both ill follwed what you said lambda but please would you mind to explan what lambda () mean ? and post your answer so ill mark it as solutions